# Where do you store your WorkManager files in a Multi-Module app?

Tags: android, android-workmanager, multi-module

For most classes it can be intuitive what module you would want to place them in, but for WorkManager it is less clear. For example you could place it in

1. top level app module
2. designated worker module
3. domain or data module

Then there is the question of the actual workers and worker factories themselves and if they would be placed in the module they are used or all aggregated into some higher level directory.

Is there any consensus or best practice on how you structure WorkManager in multi-module project?

Answer (score 1):

You can have special module for your WorkManager code. I use "work" module name

Answer (score -1):

I personally store it in lib/application folder, next to GoRouter and GetIt locator